# How to disable toch event in IOS when scrolling my app (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, vue.js

I create app by `Vuejs` and build it with `Cordova`.

But when I start **testing** my app in **IOS**, I saw that when **scroll start** I touch some link app **don't stop scrolling**, app open a new link.

What I should do to fix it? I mean that when app scrolling, I touch screen app must stop scrolling and don't open link.

Comment: @SJN Your edits are appreciated but I urge you to stop using **so much bold formatting**. It’s rather distracting and not generally helpful. In fact, I’ve had to reject one of your edits just now because it looked essentially like vandalism due to just making random text bold.

Comment: it's not my formatting text

Comment: That’s why the comment was addressed to user SJN, who edited the question, and not to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) resolve my problem